# How to create SecKey from pem file in Swift

Tags: swift, security, cryptography

I'm trying to create a `SecKey` using `SecKeyCreateWithData`. I'm loading the private key from a .pem file, and I create the key pair like this.

```
openssl genrsa -des3 -out WM_IO_my_rsa_key_pair 2048
```

Here is the code, but I get a SecKeyCreate init(RSAPublicKey) failed: -50 error.

```
import UIKit
import Security

func createKey(pem: String) -> SecKey? {
    let attributes: [NSObject : NSObject] = [
       kSecAttrKeyType: kSecAttrKeyTypeRSA,
       kSecAttrKeyClass: kSecAttrKeyClassPrivate,
       kSecAttrKeySizeInBits: NSNumber(value: 2048)
    ]

    let privateKey = pem
        .replacingOccurrences(of: "-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----", with: "")
        .replacingOccurrences(of: "-----END PRIVATE KEY-----", with: "")
        .split(separator: "\n").joined()

    guard let privateKeyData = Data(base64Encoded: privateKey, options: .ignoreUnknownCharacters) else {
        return nil
    }

    var error: Unmanaged<CFError>?
    return SecKeyCreateWithData(privateKeyData as CFData, attributes as CFDictionary, &error)
}

let privateKey = """
-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----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-----END PRIVATE KEY-----
"""

createKey(pem: privateKey)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The pem key is base64 encoded, so you need to decode it first:

```swift
guard let privateKeyData = Data(base64Encoded: privateKey, options: .ignoreUnknownCharacters) else {
   ...
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! I'm still not able to get it working.

Comment: What errors are you getting? What is the value of `privateKey`?

Comment: SecKeyCreate init(RSAPrivateKey) failed: -50

Comment: I load the private key from the pem file and then strip out the begin and end headers.

Comment: I updated the code example with a new sample private key so you can see example.

Comment: Thank you for adding enough code for me to run it and check, this is very helpful. The error text is "RSA private key creation from data failed" which means the key data is not an RSA key. How did you generate it?

Comment: Yes, thank you. I had to remove the encryption and use an RSA key.